# How can I get selected data list and structure the data list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to structure my input data but I am not getting what I want. The input data is dynamic which will come from the database.

Suppose I have this below JSX. I want to get the value from the user that he selected and also the product title which is exist on the `products`. Note that list data is dynamic I have hardcoded the values.

```
{products.map((product, i) => {
                return (
                  <li onChange={(e) => getItemValues(e.target, product)}>
                    <label className="container_radio">
                      Medium size
                      <span>+ $5.00</span>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        value={5.00}
                        name={'Medium size'}
                      />
                      <span className="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
<li onChange={(e) => getItemValues(e.target, product)}>
                    <label className="container_radio">
                      Extra Largse size
                      <span>+ $8.00</span>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        value={8.00}
                        name={'Extra Largse size'}
                      />
                      <span className="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
```

Here is the function to get the data and save it in a state

```
 const getItemValues = (e, product) => {
    setItemDetail((prevValue) => [
      ...prevValue,
      { [e.name]: e.value },
      { title: product.title },
    ]);
  };
```

The above code output is:

```
[0: {Extra Largse size: '8.0'}
1: {Medium size: '5.00'}
2: {title: 'Barnes Chapman'}]
```

I want something like this

```
[{title: 'Barnes Chapman', options:{extra large size: '8.0',Medium size: '5.00' } }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to find the product details from the `ItemDetail` array. Try something like below.

```
const getItemValues = (e, product) => {
    setItemDetail((prevValue) => {
      const existingProduct = prevValue.find(item => item.title === product.title);
      if(existingProduct) {
         existingProduct.options = {...existingProduct.options, [e.name]: e.value}
           return [...prevValue];
      } else { /* new entry */
        return [...prevValue, {title: product.title, options:{[e.name]: e.value}}]
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: I am facing some issues the state is only updating twice after the 3rd time when I click on the radio button it is not updating the state.

Comment: Try changing the `onChange` from `li` to `input`

Comment: not working bro:( after the 3rd it is going to the if statement but not updating the state

Comment: @Jerin Can you try `return [...prevValue];` instead of `return prevValue;`